# How can I compare two arrays of objects and change a value for those that are found in both arrays?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have two arrays of objects:

```
let array1 = [
          {
           id: 1,
           name: 'snow'
          },
          {
           id: 4,
           name: 'jo'
          },
          {
           id: 8,
           name: 'bran'
          },
          {
           id: 12,
           name: 'gondo'
          },
          {
           id: 13,
           name: 'peter'
          }
        ]

let array2 = [
      {
       id: 3,
       name: 'brim'
      },
      {
       id: 4,
       name: 'not-jo'
      },
      {
       id: 8,
       name: 'not-bran'
      },
      {
       id: 13,
       name: 'spleen'
      }
    ]
```

I want to find all the objects in array2 that match by id with array1, and change their name values to match the name values in array1.

In my pseudocode:

```
array1.forEach((person)=> {
 if(person.id is equal to person.id in array2){
   person.name = person.name in array1
 }
})
```

Comment: it depends on the size of the arrays. btw, what have you tried?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this :

```
array2.map(function(x){ 
       var result=array1.filter(a1=> a1.id==x.id);
       if(result.length>0) { x.name=result[0].name;}
       return x })
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop through each element and compare there ids. If they match update the name:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
  for (var k = 0; k < array1.length; k++) {
    if (array2[i].id == array1[k].id) {
      array2[i].name = array1[k].name;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Try it:

```js
let array1 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'snow'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'jo'
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: 'bran'
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    name: 'gondo'
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    name: 'peter'
  }
]

let array2 = [{
    id: 3,
    name: 'brim'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'not-jo'
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: 'not-bran'
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    name: 'spleen'
  }
]
console.log(array2);
for (var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
  for (var k = 0; k < array1.length; k++) {
    if (array2[i].id == array1[k].id) {
      array2[i].name = array1[k].name;
      break;
    }
  }
}
console.log(array2);
```

Comment: It's a O(n2) loop, if array1 and array2 length is 1000 or more, it's very slow

Comment: Its an o(n*m)  and if performance is an issue then best that can be done are  optimizations that can it  down to O(log n)(m+1)

Comment: Additionally, the cost of creating the hash table in the worse case could be o(n) and it lookups could have a worse case of o(n) although o(1) is taken for granted. Bu there is also the overhead of the hash function and the cost of the lookup. For these reason for smaller data sets, like the one in question, the overhead of trying to optimize the algorithm does not pay off. For larger data sets it will.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that

```
var idDict = {};//a dictionary to lookup array1 id
for(var idx=0;idx<array1.length;idx++) {
    idDict[array1[idx].id] = array1[idx].name;
}
for(var idx=0;idx<array2.length;idx++) {
   if (idDict[array2[idx].id]) {
        array2[idx].name = idDict[array2[idx].id];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and store the reference to each `id` and then update `array2`.

```js
let array1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'snow' }, { id: 4, name: 'jo' }, { id: 8, name: 'bran' }, { id: 12, name: 'gondo' }, { id: 13, name: 'peter' }],
    array2 = [{ id: 3, name: 'brim' }, { id: 4, name: 'not-jo' }, { id: 8, name: 'not-bran' }, { id: 13, name: 'spleen' }],
    map = new Map(array1.map(o => [o.id, o]));

array2.forEach(o => map.has(o.id) && (o.name = map.get(o.id).name));

console.log(array2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

array2.filter(o => array1.find(o2 => o.id === o2.id))