# How can I compare two arrays of objects and change a property for those that are not found in another arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays of object

```
var array1 = [{ ID:"1", IsChecked : true}, 
              { ID:"2", IsChecked : true},
              { ID:"3", IsChecked : true},
              { ID:"4", IsChecked : true}]

var array2 = [{ ID:"1", IsChecked : true},
              { ID:"2", IsChecked : true}]
```

i want to compare both the arrays of objects and change a property of array1(IsChecked : false) for those object that are not found in array2 ?

This is what my expected result should look like:

```
array1 = [{ ID:"1", IsChecked : true}, 
          { ID:"2", IsChecked : true},
          { ID:"3", IsChecked : false},
          { ID:"4", IsChecked : false}]
```

This is what i tried:

```
array1= new Map(array1.map(o => [o.ID, o]));

array2.forEach(o => map.has(o.ID) && (o.IsChecked= map.get(o.ID).IsChecked == true ? true: false));
```

But this does not giving the expected answer

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the map the `array2`, because you need to update `array1` with the previously collected values for the decision of updating.

```js
var array1 = [{ ID: "1", IsChecked: true }, { ID: "2", IsChecked: true }, { ID: "3", IsChecked: true }, { ID: "4", IsChecked: true }],
    array2 = [{ ID: "1", IsChecked: true }, { ID: "2", IsChecked: true }],
    map = new Map(array2.map(({ ID, IsChecked }) => [ID, IsChecked]));

array1.forEach(o => {
    if (map.get(o.ID)) {
        return;
    }
    o.IsChecked = false;
});

console.log(array1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: As soon as I saw the question, I knew who would post the answer. Good job @Nina Scholz :)

Comment: @Nina Scholz :Thank you. Even i was expecting answer from you. What i have tried is also from your old answer but little bit modified.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45230436/how-can-i-compare-two-arrays-of-objects-and-change-a-value-for-those-that-are-fo

Comment: Just a question, does it have to be this complicated? :-)

Comment: I was wondering if the solution I proposed was simpler, but I guess in times of time complexity using a map might be better for larger datasets, so I agree with you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
var array1 = [
  { ID: "1", IsChecked: true },
  { ID: "2", IsChecked: true },
  { ID: "3", IsChecked: true },
  { ID: "4", IsChecked: true }
];

var array2 = [{ ID: "1", IsChecked: true }, { ID: "2", IsChecked: true }];

array1
  .filter(el => JSON.stringify(array2).indexOf(JSON.stringify(el)) == -1)
  .forEach(el => (el.IsChecked = false));

console.log(array1);
```

Alternatively, you can use

```
array1
  .filter(el => array2.map(({ID})=>ID).indexOf(el.ID) == -1)
  .forEach(el => (el.IsChecked = false));
```

Comment: This is returning false to every objects of an array

Comment: As i checked now, your answer is also correct, the thing is your answer strictly checks the equality of an elements in both the arrays of objects, i.e, it works only if the same no of elements present in both the arrays of object. But in my case i had var array1 =  { ID: "1", IsChecked: true, Region:"null" } and var array2 =  { ID: "1", IsChecked: true }, And i am sorry for not mentioning the another property in my question as i thought that it is ignorable. Thank you once again.

Comment: Yeah, which is why I proposed an alternate solution. That checks only for ID, so even if array2 has 10 properties for every object, it would still work. :-)

Comment: Yes, i agree @theapologist